# How would I add a variable to my PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, addition

I am making a test version of adding users to an array and need to find a way to add the user's name variable to my array.

I am using Repl.it's PHP Web Server, which means it runs in a browser (because Chrome OS) and just have PHP. My code looks somewhat like :

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
You will be added to a list of users
<?php
$usernames = array("John Kennedy", "Barrack Ohbama", "Abraham Lincon")
array_push ($usernames, $_POST["name"]);
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
    echo $usernames[$x];
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I plug it in, I get:

```
172.18.0.1:51360 [500]: /list.php - syntax error, unexpected 'array_push' (T_STRING) in /home/runner/list.php on line 8
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon:

```
$usernames = array("John Kennedy", "Barrack Ohbama", "Abraham Lincon");
#                                                                     ^
```

PHP is sometimes unclear about error messaging and takes some getting used to.

Comment: Adding to @ggorlen's answer, you have a var called $arrlength that is supposedly an integer, but it is never declared. Instead you probably want `count($usernames)`

Answer (score 0):

You can always add new elements to array using array_push variant:

```
<?php
$usernames[] = $_POST["name"];
?>
```

If you want to set the key of new element, is also allowed

```
<?php
$usernames[$key] = $_POST["name"];
?>
```

https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php